# LINQ Where(predicate) vs. FirstOrDefault(predicate)

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Are there any appreciable performance differences between:

```
something.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
```

and

```
something.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

?

I tend to use both, but am wondering if there's a clear winner when it comes to performance.

Comment: As with most forms of optimizations, the best choice is to try it yourself and see what happens. Do your own benchmarks to see what's best for your application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on whether this `Where` is against an `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`.
In case of `IQueryable` the difference is based on implementation of the provider but it is more likely there will be no difference and would yield same query.

In case of IEnumerable it should be negligible.