# Semantic differences between FirstOrDefault() and Where() in sqlite-net

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sqlite, sqlite-net

More a clarity question than an actual question as I have found the solution. I just don't understand the reasoning...

Using SQLLite 3.8.3.1 Using SQLite-net 2.1

I see a distinct difference between running a `.Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault()` to running a `.FirstOrDefault(lambda)`.

As far as my experience with Linq goes, database LINQ providers will treat both of these essentially the same (`.FirstOrDefault(lambda)` may be a little faster if it's optimized properly, but by and large, these two calls will take roughly the same time to run).

However, in SQLite-net, I am seeing the following results on a table with ~40,000 records in it:

When running `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)`, I am seeing the time taking on a Core-i7 to be between **2200ms to 3700ms**. On a Surface RT (1st gen) this actually takes around 20,000ms-30,000ms..

When running `.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()`, I am seeing the time taking on the same Core-i7 to be between **16ms-20ms**. On a Surface RT, this takes around 30ms.

My question is whether this is just a bug, or if that's a conscious design decision. If it's a design decision - I would love to understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: There is no semantic difference between the two approaches, so no design decision could possibly justify causing a simple query to take 100 to 1000 times as long. However, it's hard to come to any additional conclusions without more information. What is the SQL that's being produced by each query? How are your benchmark tests structured? How many entries are in your database, and with what kind of indexes? etc.

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661319/linq-wherepredicate-vs-firstordefaultpredicate

Comment: @ChristosPaisios: This does not really apply. Sqlite-net returns a table object that implements one method one way and the other another.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: As I said in my question.. I understand that generally speaking the should not be a difference. But the SQL lite net folks seem to disagree. There is no easy way of looking at the SQL produced from sqlitenet linq calls. The answer below seems to say what I was suspecting. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Where` is directly translated into an SQL WHERE clause, while `.FirstOrDefault(lambda)` reads unfiltered records from the database and then checks whether they match.

In theory, it would be possible to automatically translate the latter into the former, but in practice, this is not done.
This is neither a conscious design decision nor a bug; it's simply a theoretically possible optimization has not been implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have not contributed to the library, so I am not really complaining - I am happy I get to use a ready made wrapper. However.. As food for thought.. When something is presenting itself one way, it's generally a good idea to actually behave in the way it purports. This specific behavior, while it may not be strictly a bug, is damn close to one, in my mind. Thanks for verifying the behavior for me. The workaround is simple and works well for me.